# Insert or update an entry in a nested array with a mongoDB document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document withing my collection:

```
{
  _id: ...
  data: [
    { year: '2023', week: '04', value: 1 },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to dynamically update elements within the data array of a document.

I have this update query

```
collection.updateOne(
  { 
    _id: new ObjectId(uId), 
   'data.year': <insert value>, 
   'data.week': <insert value>
  },
  { $set: { 'data.$': <new entry> } }
```

But it's not quite doing what I expect.

If I create a loop

```
const data = [
  { year: '2023', week: '04', value: 1 }
  { year: '2023', week: '05', value: 1 }
  { year: '2023', week: '06', value: 1 }
]

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i ++) {

  for await (let entry of data) {
    const res = await collection.updateOne(
      { 
        _id: new ObjectId(uId), 
       'data.year': entry.year, 
      'data.week': entry.week
     },
    { $set: { 'data.$': entry } }
    
    if(res.matchedCount === 0) {
      // this means that it does not exist so lets add it to the data array with a different update one query

      await collection.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId(uId) }, { 
        $push: { 
          'data': {
             $each: [stat],
             $sort: { year: 1, week: 1 }
          }
        } 
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```
First iteration: 3 entries in data array --> Correct
Second iteration: 3 entries in data array --> Correct
Third iteration: 4 entries in data array --> Wrong
Fifth iteration: 5 entries in data array --> Wrong
Sixths iteration: 6 entries in data array --> Wrong
```

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Check the doc : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations
The query document should only contain a single condition on the array field to which it is applied. Multiple conditions may override each other internally and lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

using `$elemMatch` seems to fix the problem.

```
collection.updateOne(
  { 
    _id: new ObjectId(uId), 
   $elemMatch: { 
     year: stat.year.toString(), 
     week: stat.week.toString() } 
}
  },
  { $set: { 'data.$': <new entry> } }
```